# destructor not executing in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I have following code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Fred
{
    private:
        char* _cptr;

    public:

        Fred()
        {
            _cptr = new char[strlen("Hello World") + 1];
            strcpy(_cptr, "Hello World");
        }

        ~Fred()
        {
            cout << "Fred::~Fred(): " << _cptr << endl;
            delete _cptr;
        }

        void Display() const
        {
            cout << "Fred::Display() _cptr: " << _cptr << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Fred* p = new Fred();
    if (p == NULL)
        cout << "fail" << endl;
    p->Display() ;

    p = NULL;
    delete p;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT
Fred::Display() _cptr: Hello World
009A02D8

```
int main()
{
    Fred* p = new Fred();
    if (p == NULL)
        cout << "fail" << endl;
    p->Display() ;

    //p = NULL;
    delete p;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT
Fred::Display() _cptr: Hello World
Fred::~Fred(): Hello World

**Any idea on why destructor is NOT working in First Case(p = NULL).**

Thanks
MAP

Comment: Switch these lines: `p = NULL;
    delete p;` `delete NULL;` is a NOP and you're leaking the origonal instance.

Comment: Why would it? You are not deleting the pointer returned by `new`.

Comment: disagree with the "close as typo" vote - it seems to me that OP intentionally wrote the code this way and doesn't understand the meaning of it

Comment: @M.M Just as _@Baum_ said. It's trivial.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But it is not "a problem that can no longer be reproduced", nor a "simple typographical error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the flow in the first case:

1. You allocate a new instance of `Fred` using the new operator
2. You call some methods with it (inconsequential to the question).
3. You assign `NULL` to the pointer, effectively losing the object you created.
4. You run `delete` on the `NULL` pointer.

Since `delete` is not run on a valid object, the destructor cannot be called.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you never deleted the object allocated by `new Fred()`.

You make `p` into a null pointer before deleting the object. The object still exists, it just has no pointers pointing to it. The name `p` is no longer associated with that object in any way. And then `delete p;` does nothing, since deleting a null pointer is defined to do nothing.